# Proof by induction of Bernoulli's inequality $ (1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

I am working on getting the hang of proofs by induction, and I was hoping the community could give me feedback on how to format a proof of this nature:

Let $x > -1$ and $n$ be a positive integer. Prove Bernoulli's inequality:
$$ (1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$$

**Proof**:

Base Case: For $n=1$, $1+x = 1+x$ so the inequality holds.

Induction Assumption: Assume that for some integer $k\ge1$, $(1+x)^k \ge 1+kx$.

Inductive Step: We must show that $(1+x)^{k+1} \ge 1+(k+1)x$

*Proof of Inductive Step*: 
$$\begin{align*}
(1+x)^k &\ge 1+kx \\
(1+x)(1+x)^k &\ge (1+x)(1+kx)\\
(1+x)^{k+1} &\ge  1 + (k+1)x + kx^2 \\
 1 + (k+1)x + kx^2 &> 1+(k+1)x \quad (kx^2 >0) \\
\Rightarrow (1+x)^{k+1} &\ge 1 + (k+1)x \qquad \qquad \qquad \square
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Where did you uses $x>-1$? Hint: you did use it.

Comment: When I claimed that $kx^2 >0$

Comment: Actually, you need it when you multiply both sides by $1+x$.  Also, since $x$ can be 0, $kx^2\ge0$

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/475309/173147

Comment: Why we need to multiply both sides by $1+x$ in the second row of inductive step?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you have is perfectly acceptable. The calculations could be organized a little more neatly:

$$\begin{align*}
(1+x)^{k+1}&=(1+x)(1+x)^k\\
&\ge(1+x)(1+kx)\\
&=1+(k+1)x+kx^2\\
&\ge1+(k+1)x\;,
\end{align*}$$

since $kx^2\ge 0$. This completes the induction step.

Answer (score 4):

This looks fine to me. Just a small note on formatting of the inequalities: I would combine the third and fourth inequalities as
$$
(1+x)^{k+1} \geq 1+(k+1)x+kx^2>1+(k+1)x,
$$
so there is no need of the fifth line. Or even
$$
(1+x)^{k+1} = (1+x)(1+x)^{k} \geq (1+x)(1+kx)=1+(k+1)x+kx^2>1+(k+1)x.
$$