# Proving inequality question using mathematical induction

Tags: induction

I'm having a really hard time on how to prove this using mathematical induction: **For all real $x>-1$, $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx$.**

Edit: (Solution with the help of comments and answer below)

If $x>-1$ then $1+x>0$ 
Base case $n=1$: $(1+x)^1\ge 1+x$. 
Induction Assumption: Assume that works for any $k\geq 1$, $(1+x)^k\geq 1+kx$ 
Inductive step: Show that $(1+x)^{k+1} \geq 1+(k+1)x$ 
$(1+x)^k\geq 1+kx$ 
Multiply $(1+x)$ on both sides: 
$(1+x)(1+x)^k\ge (1+x)(1+kx)$ 
$(1+x)(1+x)^k\ge 1+kx+x+kx^2$ 
$(1+x)^{k+1}\ge1+(k+1)x+kx^2$ 
Since $kx^2\ge0$ 
$(1+x)^{k+1}\ge1+(k+1)x$

Comment: This is known as [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) and that link contains a proof by innduction.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181702/proof-by-induction-of-bernoullis-inequality-1xn-ge-1nx) help?

Comment: Didn't know this was called Bernoulli's Inequality, thanks. I'm looking at some resolutions and trying to understand every step of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the inductive hypothesis:

$(1+x)^{k+1}=(1+x)^k(1+x)\geq (1+kx)(1+x)=1+x+kx+kx^2\geq 1+x+kx=$

$=1+(k+1)x$

We just used the inequality $kx^2\geq 0$.

Comment: I forgot to ask a step-by-step solution, cause I wasn't seeing the $(1+x)$ multiplication on both sides. I edited my draft, hope it's correct now.